# android studio problems after computer crash

Tags: android

One day  when i was working on a project my PC crashed (no blue screen, just selfcut power). After that when i opened Android Studio, i saw this:
[image]

I try reinstall everyfing: Java Jre, JDK, SDK, NDK, Android Studio. I checked all settings and dependencies in File > Project Structure (I'm working with friend, project still work for him). I tried deleting project and importing from git. Nothing worked, please help.

Comment: probably issue with android sdk.

Comment: invalidate cache and restart.. @Szymon

Comment: Invalidate cache and restart - now work, thank you.